# to take somebody vs to take somebody out

Tags: synonyms

Is there a difference between the following two sentences?

- I'll take you to a good restaurant in Paris
- I'll take you out to a good restaurant in Paris

Does "to take out" implicitly mean that I am going to pay the bill and "to take" not?

Comment: To "take someone out" to a restaurant does imply treating them. The implication is stronger than merely "taking" them, but neither absolutely indicates that you will be footing the bill. You'll want to be explicit, e.g., "I'll take you [out] to a good restaurant in Paris—my treat" or "We can go to a good restaurant in Paris that I know."

Comment: Imagine that the speaker is the driver of a taxi you just hailed. The little three-letter word is the difference between helpful and creepy.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, there's a definite pragmatic content. The 'out' may/may not make much difference to the intended / perceived meaning, but there is a familiarisation overtone when 'out' is included. "The poor old dear hardly ever gets out."

Comment: Certain constructions also tread on idioms, whose meanings might change if you alter a word. For instance *I was taken to the cleaners* versus *I was taken out to the cleaners*.

Comment: @JasonBassford What does "cleaners" mean? Could you explicitly explain the difference? Both sentences mean the same to me.

Comment: @Lawrence Could you explain better your example with the taxi driver? "to take out" here would seem that he is offering to pay the restaurant bill? Is that why it would be creepy?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista The actual idiom *take to the cleaners*, which has a specific meaning beyond its individual words, means "to deprive of money or possessions : clean out." (You can search for the expression [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)). If you were to make it *take **out** to*, the addition of that word would make the idiom (which is a set phrase) lose its meaning, giving it a more literal interpretation based on the individual words. It's an example that only applies because of the specific word *cleaners*.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista As for using *take me **out** to a restaurant* with a taxi driver, the use of *take me* ***out*** implies a date of some kind, either romantic or between family or friends. It would be highly unusual to say *take me **out** to a good restaurant* to a complete stranger, in this case a taxi driver. It would be creepy for the taxi driver to hear such an expression, which is normally reserved for a different social context.

Comment: There's also the idiom *take [person's name, or pronoun] out* (but without indicating a destination) meaning ***eliminate them***. In a sporting contest, it means ending their game or their presence in the contest or competition. In warfare or other violent scenarios, it means killing them. The context when saying "I'm going to take you out" can therefore be important. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take someone *out* to a restaurant is to go there to eat with them and likely pick up the check. To *take them* to the same place may be only to take them to that location. Perhaps to see what they are serving, drop them off there or other geographic concerns.

Another idiom is to *take someone out* without specifying a destination meaning to murder them.

Comment: @Jason Bassford mentioned in one one of the comments of my question that "to take sb out to somewhere" also implies a date of some kind, either romantic or between family or friends. If you agree, it'd be nice to add that to your answer.